# How to run Spark processing in parallel in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I would like to run a Spark application using multiple executors in parallel while trying the application on my development environment (Eclipse). It seems the Spark engine serializes all the tasks and run them using one executor.

Is there an option to run two or more tasks in parallel in Eclipse with `spark.master=local`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `spark.master="local[n]"` where `n` is the number of cores you want to assign to spark or `"*"` for all cores.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, RDD's are stored in the executor memory. That is the reason Spark performing all the tasks where data is available. I think there is no option to control the way Spark executes the tasks. Basically it creates stages based on the tasks and then determines the tasks execution.

Comment: Actually, my question was not about how to change the way Spark determines the DAG of stages an tasks. I was wondering if, given a single stage with more than one task(determined by Spark), there is a way to tell spark that two executors should take different tasks from the set and run them concurrently. The way it works in YARN mode, but, in my Eclipse...